# push notification DB managment

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Im about to use GCM for android and APNS for ios in my app.

on my server side I save in my DB the device id and account id each login.

When the user logs out I delete that entry, so the user wont receive it any more (and even if it logs in with a different account on the same device)

The scenario im thinking about is when the user uninstalls the app while he is still logged in. That means the user didnt go through the logout request, which is the request that deletes the device id entry on my DB.

Now the user installs the app again but logs in with a different account.

In my DB i'll have the same device id with 2 account ids, which means the user will get push notifications that does not belong to him (his device will keep getting notifications for the previous logged account).

To my knowledge android got device id for each app "instance" so I dont have a problem here (even though a message will be sent to a ghost device which is weird), but on ios I know the device Id you send to apns is unique to each device...

Bottom line -

Did I get anything wrong?

Solution I thought about is setting timeout for device same as the login timeout (still the interlaced time will get notifications from 2 accounts)

Still this problem look very trivial and that must be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS, an approach would be to add a key to `NSUserDefaults` to check if the app is on its first run or not.

On successive runs, if the above key is present, you do nothing since it isn't your first run.  If the key is not present yet ( first run after install ) you send a request with the deviceid, which removes the current deviceid from your server DB with all its logged in entries. You set the key to true, then you can proceed to normal login. 
This will only work if the deviceid doesn't change between installs.

I guess there is a similar mechanic for Android too.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it too, I guess that is the only way. to manually manage it myself on my DB according to the bool variable sent by the user in case of fresh install

Comment: After some work, my ios developer claimed he cannot retrieve the device id unless the user approve the push prompt.
If so, in case the user didn't approve I wont have the device id to match on my DB and delete it,that is until the user approves it.
now, i will send pushes to the same device id (pushes for the account before the uninstall).
Even if apple knows the app was uninstalled and doesn't send those pushes the the device itself, its very inefficient from my side to send those "ghost pushes"

Any ideas?

Comment: @sharongur I understand the problem, but don't really have an idea. Maybe an option would be the Keychain. It offers secure storage and will persist even if the app is deleted. You could store your first approved device id there. If at the install there is already one ID there, re-use it or unsubscribe it and proceed with a new one.